# Seeding Database in Asp.net Core, cannot create admin account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, seeding

I'm trying to create a default admin account when I start an application.
Now what I'm interested in is how to seed a database in asp.net core. I have a seed code that I run in the main program. It shows no error but does not update the database. I've been trying to change "Identity rolls" to Application Role in my SeedData, but it has no effect at all. 
I wouldn't want to change most of the code and I know it can be done with a model builder, but I don't want it that way. I think the problem is with the main program, but I don't understand what I need to change. My code is shown here.

SeedData.cs

```
namespace AspNetCoreTodo
{

public static class SeedData
{
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        await EnsureRolesAsync(roleManager);

        var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        await EnsureTestAdminAsync(userManager);
    }

    private static async Task EnsureRolesAsync(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        var alreadyExists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(Constants.AdministratorRole);

        if (alreadyExists) return;

        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Constants.AdministratorRole));
    }

    private static async Task EnsureTestAdminAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        var testAdmin = await userManager.Users
            .Where(x => x.UserName == "admin@todo.local")
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (testAdmin != null) return;

        testAdmin = new ApplicationUser { Email = "admin@todo.local", UserName = "admin@todo.local" };
        await userManager.CreateAsync(testAdmin, "NotSecure123!!");
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(testAdmin, Constants.AdministratorRole);
    }
}
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
    namespace AspNetCoreTodo.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<TodoItem> Items {get;  set;}


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

}
}
```

Program.cs

```
    namespace AspNetCoreTodo
{
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    private static void InitializeDatabase(IWebHost host)
    {
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                SeedData.InitializeAsync(services).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
}
```

Startup.cs //Configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>(); 

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
       services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthentication();
       services.AddScoped<ITodoItemService, TodoItemService>();
    }
```

Comment: Try to put debugger in `InitializeAsync()` and check it cames here.
Here you have called seeder from Program.cs, personally I prefer it to call it from `Startup.cs`

Answer (score 1):

Does your application ever goes in the method `InitializeDatabase(IWebHost host)` in `Program.cs`?

Could you please try to call your method in `Main()` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
      var webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

      InitializeDatabase(webHost);

      webHost.Run();
}
```

**Note:** You have to create that 'webHost' variable, because your method takes 'IWebHost' as a parameter. And `CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)` method returns type of `IWebHostBuilder`. Also `Run()` method will work on type of `IWebHost`.

**Note:** As Nilay noticed above, I'd also seed my database in `Startup.cs`, in the

```
if(env.isDevelopment){
   InitializeDatabase(webHost);
}
```

Because normally, seeding is a "development" purpose.

Comment: I've fixed it now it runs smoothly but It catches my exception and ""An error occurred seeding the DB." is being displayed just as I specified. It can't get a hold of my SeedData.cs.

Comment: There might be several reasons because of that.. Did you able to debug your code?

Comment: Ty for your suggestion , I fixed the problem. I had to add   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()